# Change the text of Text view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, text, view, swiftui

Let's say I have created a Text view. How can I change its text later in the code? Can I use a @State property as the source for the Text view?

```
struct ContentView: View {
      var body: some View {
            Text("Hello World!")
                 .onTapGesture {
                     // How can I change its text?
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on board. You should start from [Learn to Make Apps with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/tutorials)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can! try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text = "Hallo"

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.text = "changed"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't we use something like $text? Just like other state properties?